# Unicorn behind ELB, no nginx

Tags: http, amazon-elb, unicorn

If I understand Unicorn right (and in particular from their [philosophy doc](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/PHILOSOPHY.html)) it seems like Unicorn was really designed to operate behind a reverse proxy like nginx.

**My question is:** can I drop nginx from my HTTP stack, considering we have an ELB at the top acting as the reverse proxy?

I didn't find any issues on initial tests, but just wondering if anyone out there has experience on this front already.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [Unicorn philosophy doc](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/PHILOSOPHY.html), the most important requirement is that the reverse proxy buffers requests and responses so that Unicorn isn't held up by slow clients. I can't find any definitive information, but this [forum post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=315499&#315499) and the following part of the [ELB documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-listener-config.html) imply that ELB does do some buffering in HTTP/HTTPS mode (but not in TCP/SSL mode).

> When you use HTTP (layer 7) for both front-end and back-end connections, your load balancer parses the headers in the request and terminates the connection before re-sending the request to the registered instance(s).